# How to write to a pixel buffer line by line in glium?

Tags: rust, glium

When uploading a decoded image to a pixel buffer, sometimes the lines contain a stride. That is, the lines are bigger than the image lines, for performance reasons (alignment). So if we want to upload the image called `slice`, we either upload it entirely if it has no stride (`linesize==width`) or we upload line by line:

```
    //If the linesize is equal to width then we don't need to respect stride
    if linesize == width as usize {
        pixel_buffer.write(slice);
    } else {
        for line in 0..height {
            let current_line_start = (line * width) as usize;
            let s = &slice[(current_line_start)..(current_line_start + linesize)];
            pixel_buffer.write(s);
        }
    }
```

However, `pixel_buffer.write(s)` fails if `s.len()` is not the same as `pixel_buffer`'s size.

Reading https://docs.rs/glium/0.30.0/glium/texture/pixel_buffer/struct.PixelBuffer.html, it's not clear how to write by pieces. It looks like `map_write` might do it:

```
pub fn map_write(&mut self) -> WriteMapping<'_, T>
```

> Maps the buffer in memory for writing only.

But how do I write to `WriteMapping`?

**PS: I think this is not the solution because I'd have to wait for the GPU map to occur. I just want to send data to the pixel buffer as fast as possible**

Comment: I think you might want to look into the varius `slice` and `slice_mut` methods of pixel buffer. It seems `WriteMapping` has a `set` method, but that's just for a single value of the mapping, so that's bound to be very inefficient.

Comment: @Lagerbaer but "This method builds an object that represents a slice of the buffer. No actual operation OpenGL is performed.". How do I force the OpenGL operation after?

Comment: Well then you have your slice, and read up on the documentation of the slice struct, which will have some sort of `write` method.

Comment: @Lagerbaer indeed, it returns https://docs.rs/glium/0.30.0/glium/buffer/struct.BufferMutSlice.html, but its write method https://docs.rs/glium/0.30.0/glium/buffer/struct.BufferMutSlice.html#method.write simply does the same thing as in `PixelBuffer`, it requires a whole data.

Comment: Yeah but that will be the whole data for _that_ slice.